# Browser TypeError “fsGetSearchListener is not a function” on FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

We recently went live with a website. I set up an onerror event handler in the client-side Javascript-code to see what kind of errors users are getting (if any). The handler sends the error message and user agent string to my server log. I haven't got a lot of errors at all, but there is one which is pretty mysterious to me. It and occurs at least with Firefox versions 43 and 44 (Windows NT 6.3 - 10.0). Haven't been able to repeat it myself, and the error occurs when the browser enters my site with a gclid parameter (from adwords).

This is the error-message:

"TypeError: fsGetSearchListener(...) is not a function"

I get about 5 of these every day.

Example of an user agent string with this issue: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0

What's really weird about this is that googling fsGetSearchListener doesn't give any results.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, about 400 events with the exact error: TypeError: fsGetSearchListener(...) is not a function. As you mention, they all are from modern Firefox browsers (most v44), they are all from windows OS and most have Google as referer. No idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

We've started detecting these errors across a few different customer sites with with [TrackJS](https://trackjs.com/) It appears to be an error in a Firefox extension, however we have not been able to identify which one.

The errors appear to come from a `<script>` tag embedded on the page itself. Our theory is that some extension is doing a document.write and including custom script, which is breaking.